# how to mock an interface using PowerMockito in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

```
req1(an object of request type 1)
req2(an object of request type 2)


    class response{
        public TxnResp txnResp(){ 
            TxnResp txnResp = service.txn(req1 , req2);
            return txnResp;
       }
    }
```

I am using `Powermockito` for mocking in my junit testing.

"txn" is an interface. I need to mock this line  `TxnResp txnResp = service.txn(req1 , req2);` my test class. Because calling `txn` is returning some value's from the webservice, which are specified in the next line.

`txnResp` contains following values storeNo,retailerId and password. It has its own bean class, so that we can set values like `txnResp.setStoreId(1);`

Could any one please help me to mock the above interface 'txn' and return value to `txnResp`.

I am stuck for the last 5 hours in it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What does this mean: *"txn" is an interface*? `txn` is clearly a method of `service`. Do you mean that there is some interface, say, `Txn`, and `txn` is a *method* of that interface?

Comment: yes!txn is a method of that interface.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion plain `Mockito` would be enough in your situation.

If `service` is a dependency that is injected (via constructor, setter i.e.), you could try something following:

```
public class ResponseTest{

   @InjectMocks
   private Response response;

   @Mock
   private Service serviceMock;

   @Before
   public void init(){
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void test(){
        // Arrange
        TxnResp txnResp = new TxnResp(...);

        Mockito.doReturn(txnResp).when(serviceMock).txn(
           Mockito.any(ReqType1.class), Mockito.any(ReqType2.class));

       // Act and assert...      
   }
}
```

Comment: Could I know what is "serviceMock" inside when condition?

Comment: PowerMockito.spy(Response.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(txnResp).when(Service.class, "txn",Matchers.anyObject(),Matchers.anyObject());
This is what i did in my test class,but its not excecuting.

Comment: instead of "serviceMock", it should have just been "service", i.e. the `@Mock`'ed `Service` instance

Comment: yes my mistake. I tend to use Mock as sufix to distinguish real impls from mocked / stubbed ones.